# vue.js and firebase query giving wrong array count

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js

something weird is going on. I am using Vue.js and Firebase. my query is simple. I have 3 documents in the database

```
let tagRef = db.collection('tags')
        tagRef = tagRef.where('gid', '==', this.$store.getters.gid)
        tagRef.onSnapshot(snapshot => {
            this.tags = []
            snapshot.docChanges().forEach(change => {
                let docs = change.doc
                this.tags.push(docs.data())
                console.log(this.tags.length)
            })
        })
```

as you can see I am logging the array length to the console. when I refresh the page my console log reads 1 1 2 however when a change is made is reads correctly 1 2 3

I am not sure why it is doing this.

When I change the console.log from this.tags.length to this.tags attached are the screen shots of what I get.

on page refresh

[image]

when a change occurs

[image]

any help is greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:

This is a game. players can tag each other. when a player gets tagged they are disabled temporarily until their tag is complete. the second piece is each player can be tagged no more than 3 times.

In the created() hook I query for the tags and I am using the realtime part of firebase so anytime something changes with the tag database the code is updated.

I have a method as seen below:

```
countTags(team) {
            return this.tags.filter(function (tag) {
                if(tag.tagged == team.team_id){
                    return team
                }
            })
        },
```

This method is supposed to return the tags based off of the team id. i the html i have this

```
:class="{'taglimit' : countTags(team).length >= 3}"
```

which will add the "taglimit" class if the count is 3 or greater.

SECOND UPDATE:

When I run this query in the created hook i have issues

```
let tagRef = db.collection('tags')
    tagRef = tagRef.where('gid', '==', this.$store.getters.gid)
    tagRef.onSnapshot(snapshot => {
        this.tags = []
        snapshot.docChanges().forEach(change => {
            let docs = change.doc
            this.tags.push(docs.data())
        })
    })
```

but when I run this query I don't

```
let tagRef = db.collection('tags')
        tagRef = tagRef.where('gid', '==', this.$store.getters.gid)
        tagRef.get().then((snapshot) => {
            snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                let tag = doc.data()
                tag.id = doc.id
                this.tags.push(tag)
            })
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        })
```

The problem is I need to update the code every time the tag database changes.

THIRD UPDATE

I think I found the issue. I moved this.tags = [] outside the query and everything appears to be working fine now. so now the query looks like this.

```
this.tags = []
let tagRef = db.collection('tags')
    tagRef = tagRef.where('gid', '==', this.$store.getters.gid)
    tagRef.onSnapshot(snapshot => {
        snapshot.docChanges().forEach(change => {
            let docs = change.doc
            this.tags.push(docs.data())
            console.log(this.tags.length)
        })
    })
```

FOURTH UPDATE:

here is the HTML

```
<v-dialog v-model="dialog" persistent transition="scale-transition" fullscreen light>
            <v-btn
            slot="activator"
            fixed
            dark
            fab
            bottom
            right
            color="blue-grey darken-2"
            class="pulse-button"
            >
            <v-icon>directions_run</v-icon>
            </v-btn>
            <v-card color="rgba(224, 224, 224, .95)">
                <v-container grid-list-md text-xs-center>
                    <v-layout row wrap class="tagform-container">
                        <v-btn dark fab right absolute small color="grey darken-3"  @click="dialog = false"><v-icon>close</v-icon></v-btn>
                        <v-layout justify-center>
                            <v-card-title class="display-2 font-weight-black">TAG!</v-card-title>
                        </v-layout>
                        <v-card-text class="subheading">Select a team you want to tag. Note, you only have one tag per game. Use it wisely!</v-card-text>
                        <v-flex xs4 class="add-flex" v-for="team in activeTeams" :key="team.id" >
                            <div class="tag-card" 
                                :class="{'disabled' : activeTag(team).length > 0, 'taglimit' : countTags(team).length >= 3}" 
                                height="100%" 
                                color="white" 
                                style="background:#fff;" 
                                @click="activeTag(team).length > 0 || countTags(team).length >= 3 ? '' : selectedTeam(team)"
                                >
                                <v-layout justify-center>
                                    <v-card-title class="title">{{team.team_name}}</v-card-title>
                                </v-layout>
                                <v-responsive>
                                    <img class="avatar" v-bind:src="team.url">
                                </v-responsive>
                                <v-flex>
                                    <v-card-text class="body-2 text-uppercase">Tap to select</v-card-text>
                                </v-flex>
                            </div>
                        </v-flex>
                    </v-layout>
                </v-container>
            </v-card>
        </v-dialog>
```

There is more but this is the part that counts.

Here is some more of the code

```
data() {
        return {
            feedback: null,
            teams: [],
            taggedteam: null,
            dialog: false,
            stepper: false,
            emojiinput: '',
            search: '',
            e1: 1,
            tag: null,
            tags: [],
            completedtags: [],
            tagstates: []
        }
    },
computed: {
        activeTeams: function () {
            let thisTeam = this.$store.getters.player.team_id
            return this.teams.filter(function (team) {
                if(team.team_id !== thisTeam)
                    return team
            })
        }
    },
```

One of the Methods:

```
countTags(team) {
            return this.tags.filter(function (tag) {
                if(tag.tagged == team.team_id){
                    return team
                }
            })
        },
```

finally the created hook

```
created(){
        // get teams
        let teamRef = db.collection('teams')
        teamRef = teamRef.where('gid', '==', this.$store.getters.gid)
        teamRef = teamRef.orderBy('team_id')
        teamRef.onSnapshot(snapshot => {
            snapshot.docChanges().forEach(change => {
                if(change.type == 'added') {
                    let docs = change.doc

                    let leaderRef = db.collection('leaderboard')
                    leaderRef = leaderRef.where('gid', '==', this.$store.getters.gid)
                    leaderRef = leaderRef.where('team', '==', docs.data().team_id)
                    leaderRef = leaderRef.where('missioncomplete', '==', true)
                    leaderRef.onSnapshot(snapshot => {
                        if(snapshot.empty) {
                            // team has not completed the mission so they can still be tagged
                            this.teams.push(docs.data())
                        }
                    })

                }
            })
        })

        // get tags
        this.tags = []
        let tagRef = db.collection('tags')
        tagRef = tagRef.where('gid', '==', this.$store.getters.gid)
        tagRef.onSnapshot(snapshot => {
            snapshot.docChanges().forEach(change => {
                let docs = change.doc
                this.tags.push(docs.data())
            })
        })

        // get tag states
        this.tagstates = []
        let tagStateRef = db.collection('tagstate')
        tagStateRef = tagStateRef.where('gid', '==', this.$store.getters.gid)
        tagStateRef = tagStateRef.where('state', '==', true)
        tagStateRef = tagStateRef.orderBy('tag')
        tagStateRef.onSnapshot(snapshot => {
            snapshot.docChanges().forEach(change => {
                let docs = change.doc
                this.tagstates.push(docs.data())
            })
        })

        if(this.$store.getters.player.team_id) {
            // check to see if this player has already tagged someone
            let tagRef = db.collection('tags')
            tagRef = tagRef.where('tagger', '==', this.$store.getters.player.team_id)
            tagRef = tagRef.where('gid', '==', this.$store.getters.gid)
            tagRef.onSnapshot(snapshot => {
                snapshot.docChanges().forEach(change => {
                    let docs = change.doc
                    this.completedtags.push(docs.data())
                })
            })
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem but without success (it works well for me). However it is difficult to be sure I reproduced it correctly since you don't share your full component code (in particular the data object). I think you should initialize the tags data object outside of the callback, or better directly in the data object. If you share more of your code and explain your exact goal we may help you better.

Comment: interestingly enough, I tried to reproduce this using my iPhone and in Safari on my desktop but could not. I am on a local server and it appears to only be happening in chrome. Not sure why that is. would you still like to see the rest of the code?

Comment: Yes, sure! and also explain what is your functional goal with this listener pls.

Comment: I have updated the question with more info. Let me know if you need more. I am still getting weird stuff in Chrome so I know I am doing something wrong :)

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I update the question a second time with new information

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I think I found the issue. I moved this.tags = [] outside the query and everything appears to be working fine now

Comment: @RenaudTarnec ok I spoke too soon. now the code is not updating on everychange.

Comment: I definitely think you should initialize tags outside the loop, as I said in my first comment (" I think you should initialize the tags data object outside of the callback, or better directly in the data object."). Let me have a look at your code.

Comment: The entire page? how do I do that in stack overflow?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190960/discussion-between-jason-and-renaud-tarnec).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit difficult to dive into your code without knowing the exact relationship between teams/tags and their respective limits.

But I've understood from the discussion that you want to change the class of a DOM element if the result of the query is more that 3 documents.

You'll find a possible approach below, which shows how to manange the class change (and also, if needed how to maintain the `tags` array in the `data` object, i.e. being reactive to database changes).

```
<template>
  <div :class="{ taglimit: isTagLimit }">Test</div>
</template>

<script>
const fb = require("../firebaseConfig.js");
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      tags: [],
      isTagLimit: false
    };
  },

  created: function() {
    let tagRef = fb.db.collection("tags");
    tagRef = tagRef.where("gid", "==", this.$store.getters.gid);
    tagRef.onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
      console.log(querySnapshot.size);
      //The next if is sufficient to activate the taglimit class
      if (querySnapshot.size > 3) {
        this.isTagLimit = true;
      } else {
        this.isTagLimit = false;
      }
      //If you want to update the tags property
      var t = [];
      querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
        t.push(doc.data());
      });
      this.tags = t;
    });
  }
};
</script>

<style>
.taglimit {
  color: deeppink;
}
</style>
```

Note that instead of replacing the entire `tags` array, you could listen to "atomic" changes in the Query and update the array with the changes, see  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#view_changes_between_snapshots

Comment: It wasn't exactly what I was trying to achieve. I can't just count the tags because certain tags are for certain players so I first get all the tags then with the countTags method I filter down to each team and count that. However, from your code in the query I was able to resolve the issue. Thank you so much!

Comment: Yes I understood from your code that there is some filtering based on the team values if I am not mistaken... but frankly it was a bit difficult to dive into the code and be sure that I would apply the correct filter in my answer.... :-) Happy that I could help you however!